# Time Complexity for Isomorphic Strings

Tags: java, hashmap, isomorphism

What is the time complexity of the `HashMap.containsValue()` and thus of the code? Is it `O(n2)` or the `if` condition reduces the `HashMap.containsValue()`'s complexity to `O(1)`?

```
public static boolean isIsomorphic (String s1 , String s2){

    if (s1 == null || s2 == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (s1.length() != s2.length()){
        return false;
    }

    HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < s1.length(); i++){

        if (!map.containsKey(s1.charAt(i))){

            if(map.containsValue(s2.charAt(i))){

                return false;
            }           

            else{
                map.put(s1.charAt(i), s2.charAt(i));
            }           
        }
        else{
            if( map.get(s1.charAt(i)) != s2.charAt(i)){
                return false;                   
            }               
        }           
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "isomorphic"? That one string is a permutation of the other, i.e. contains the same characters in a different order? If so, you can implement isIsomorphic in O(n) by using a better algorithm.

Comment: Read the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): *"Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the `HashMap` instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings)"*.

Answer (score 1):

containsValue() time complexity is going to be O(n+k)[n being no. of values and k being no. of keys]. Since each value is present inside a bucket, the control goes to each bucket and then traverses inside the bucket till it finds the value.